# How to mount Local Disk as C: in Windows XP

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, mount

I just installed Windows XP, which is nothing new for me - I've done it at least 20 times now, using the same installation disk each time.  However, I ran into quite a unique problem this time.  The hard drive that contains the OS (Local Disk) is mounting as `E:` by default, leaving `C:` non-existant, which messes up installation files since they try to install to `C:\filepath\program` but `C:` doesn't exist.  How do I tell it to mount Local Disk as `C:` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223188

> 1. Make a full system backup of the computer and system state.
> 2. Log on as an Administrator.
> 3. Start Regedt32.exe.
> 4. Go to the following registry key:
> 5. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
> 6. Click MountedDevices.
> 7. On the Security menu, click Permissions.
> 8. Verify that Administrators have full control. Change this back when you are finished with these steps.
> 9. Quit Regedt32.exe, and then start Regedit.exe.
> 10. Locate the following registry key:
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
> 11. Find the drive letter you want to change to (new). Look for "\DosDevices\C:".
> 12. Right-click \DosDevices\C:, and then click Rename.
>
> Note You must use Regedit instead of Regedt32 to rename this registry key.
> Rename it to an unused drive letter "\DosDevices\Z:".
>
> This frees up drive letter C.
>
> 13. Find the drive letter you want changed. Look for "\DosDevices\D:".
> 14. Right-click \DosDevices\D:, and then click Rename.
> 15. Rename it to the appropriate (new) drive letter "\DosDevices\C:".
> 16. Click the value for \DosDevices\Z:, click Rename, and then name it back to "\DosDevices\D:".
> 17. Quit Regedit, and then start Regedt32.
> 18. Change the permissions back to the previous setting for Administrators (this should probably be Read Only).
> 19. Restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having two drive letters in use, you can also add C: as an alias for E:. The driver letter dialog in `diskmgmt.msc` not only has a `Change drive letter` option, but also a `Add drive letter`.

The benefit would be that existing software installations on E: do not break by the rename.